# Calculating the 4th coordinate of a tetrahedron based on three others

Tags: trigonometry

I'm doing experiments where we have microscopic regular tetrahedrons moving around in a solution. We can detect and track the location of the 4 corners of the tetrahedron using some clever microscopy.

However, sometimes, one of the corners is not detected by our script. Based on the coordinates of the 3 detected corners, I should be able to tell where the final corner is on our coordinate grid, since I know the direction the missing point should be pointing relative to the remaining triangle from the previous successful tracking point.

Unfortunately, I have no clue how to get to the coordinates of the fourth corner from the XYZ coordinates of the 3 corners I know.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are the corners distinguishable? Otherwise there will be two possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

My question is almost an exact duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372556/given-three-points-on-a-tetrahedron-find-the-4th) answer on stackoverflow.

Average your three points to get the center of the triangle:

$$center = (a + b + c) / 3$$

Calculate the normal vector by taking the cross product of two of the sides:

$$normal = (c - a) \times (b - a)$$

Normalize the normal vector (make it of unit length):

$$normal_{unit} = normal / |normal|$$

Scale the normal by the height of regular tetrahedron:

$$normal_{scaled}= normal_{unit}* \sqrt{2/3}$$

Now, your two points are:

$$top = center + normal_{scaled}$$
$$bottom = center - normal_{scaled}$$